# Android add a subview to a row layout of a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, baseadapter

I have a ListView in my application with a custom adapter that extends the BaseAdapter. In the getView() method of my custom adapter a relative layout is inflated in order to display data parsed from JSON.

In SOME cases data include an image url that i want to load in an ImageView of the row's RelativeLayout. But by default this layout doesn't include a second ImageView for this purpose.

Question: Which is the appropriate way of adding a sub-element (ImageView) in the RelativeLayout depending on the data received and after its been inflated in the getView() method of my adapter? The following image is the relative layout that is inflated:

[image: Custom listview row layout]

And this is how i want it in some cases (rows of list depending on data):
[image: Custom listview row layout with image]

I should mention that i've searched for this a lot. But can't decide for a efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default put the image view always in your list item layout and make visibility as "Gone" whenever you required you can set the image and change the visibility.

```
if(imageDisplay){
   //set the image and change the visibility as "Visible"
}else{
   //set the visibility as "Gone"
}
```

Comment: I understand. Thats what i thought.. But the ImageView will always be there, is this efficient enough?

Comment: ImageView is there but the visibility is set to Gone always. So, it won't cause any issues and definitely fulfill your requirement.

Comment: You need to put the ImageView in another container view - like a FrameLayout. Why? because the bottom TextView's location will be depenent on whether or not the ImageView is visible, so instead you reference it off the FrameLayout which will resize when the ImageView is gone (but will still be present to be below)

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you Check out `ListView Animations` [HERE](https://github.com/Grishu/Animated_Listview) . In that check out the last screenshot and try out the class [ExpandedListView](https://github.com/Grishu/Animated_Listview/blob/master/ListViewwithAnimation/src/com/grishu/listviewanimations/itemmanipulationexamples/ExpandableListItemActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks, i'll check that!

Answer (score 0):

```
Message msg = data[position];
int type = getViewType(msg.type);
switch(type) {
   case TEXTVIEW:
        if(null == convertView || (null == convertView && convertView.getTag() == TEXTVIEW)) {
            convertview = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.textview);
            convertview.setTag(TEXTVIEW);

        } else {
            convertview = convertview.getTag(TEXTVIEW);
        }

        //do render your view.
        break;
   case IMAGEVIEW:
        if(null == convertView || (null == convertView && convertView.getTag() == IMAGEVIEW)) { 
            convertview = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.imageview);
            convertview.setTag(IMAGEVIEW);

        } else {
            convertview = convertview.getTag(IMAGEVIEW);
        }
        //do render your view.
        break;
}
```

Comment: Inflating a different layout should do my job too! Thanks.

Comment: Its a general efficiency question when the list grow.. So all these answers should do what i want. But what is more effective?

Comment: so what do you mean effective?what you need is,reuse convertView.